# How to solve $f'(x)=f(-x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By inspection,  $f'(x)=f(-x)$ seems only has trivial solution $f(x)=0$, is it right or wrong?

Comment: If it ain't sinusoidal, I suspect you are right.

Comment: $f''= -f$. ${}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume in addition that $f$ is twice-differentiable. Then the solutions are precisely the functions of the form
$$
f(x) = A(\sin(x) + \cos(x)).
$$

Proof: taking another derivative, we see
$$
f''(x) = -f'(-x) = -f(x).
$$
This latter condition is satisfied precisely by functions of the form $A\sin(x) + B\cos(x)$, but most of these are not solutions to the original equation. Indeed, if $f(x) = A\sin(x) + B\cos(x)$, then $f(-x) = -A\sin(x) + B\cos(x)$ whereas $f'(x) = A\cos(x) - B\sin(x)$, so we get a solution if and only if $A = B$.

There may be exotic solutions that are once but not twice-differentiable; I'm not sure. (EDIT: there are no exotic solutions, see the comment.)

Comment: Oh, any solution must automatically be twice differentiable, as is automatic from the condition. So these are all the solutions.

Comment: just to clarify (i'm not good at self-learning so I often need to clarify things), the characteristic equation of the second-order linear homogeneous differential equation $f''(x)+f(x)=0$ is $y^2+1=0\Rightarrow y=0+\pm 1i$ and so the solutions are $Ae^0(\sin(1x))+Be^0\cos(1x),$ right? Also, is any solution twice differentiable precisely because if $f(x)$ exists, then $-f(x)=f''(x)$ exists?

Comment: @SimonFraser yes, exactly on both. For twice differentaibility -- any solution is twice differentiable just because $f'(x) = f(-x)$ and $f$ is by stipulation differentiable so $x \mapsto f(-x)$ is as well.

Answer (score 1):

As to the differentiability assumption, you can avoid assuming twice differentiability by considering $g(x)=f(-x)$. Then
$$
f'(x)=g(x)\\
g'(x)=-f(x)
$$
is a linear system of dimension $2$, which by the existence theorems has a global solution. As linear functions are infinitely smooth, a consequence of the existence of the solution is that the solutions are also differentiable of any order (analytical actually).