# Solve $f'(x)=f(-x)$

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof

Here is my attempt. Start by taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$:

$$\frac{d}{dx} f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(-x).$$

This simplifies to:

$$f''(x) = -f'(-x).$$

Using the given equation we get

$$f''(x) = -f(x).$$

The general solution of this ode is

$$f(x)=A\cos x+ B\sin x,$$

where $(A,B)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Taking the first derivative results in

$$f'(x)=-A\sin x+ B\cos x.$$

For this to be equal to $f(-x)$ it suffices that $A=B$.

Hence; the set of functions satisfying the original equation reads finally

$$f(x)=A(\cos x +\sin x).$$

Questions:
Is my solution rigorous?
Other ways to find the requested set of functions?

Comment: I cannot get the negative vote. What is wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve $f'(x)=f(-x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410487/how-to-solve-fx-f-x). Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626312/for-which-a-the-de-fx-fax-has-non-zero-solution?noredirect=1.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvotes either. Maybe they didn’t read through to the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me your work looks correct, except at the end there's a sketchy part where you say "it suffices that $A=B$". That's true, but you also want it to be necessary, not just suffice, to claim that all solutions are of the form that you get. This can easily be verified by understanding that $f'(x) = f(-x)$ *for all* $x$, so in particular $f'(0) = f(0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: So, since the given equation is valid for all $x$, it is valid for $x=0$ as well. From $f'(0) = f(0)$ we get finally $A=B$. Is that ok?

Comment: @Dimitris, yes, that's ok. That shows that all solutions are of the form that you wrote and you can then finish by saying that all functions of the form are solutions by direct inspection.

Comment: Great. Thanks again! A little bit late but Happy New Year